# Output data to text file in individual rows in r

Tags: r, cat, readlines

I am trying to write code in r that:

1.)Reads every other line in a text file

2.)writes those lines to a text file

My code does these things, but the problem is that r is writing the lines to the text file in continuous format, instead of writing line by line like the original text file.

Here is my code:

```
test <- readLines("file_name.txt")
test <- test[seq(1, length(test), 2)] # reads every 2nd line
cat(test, file="E:/output_file_name.txt", sep = " ",append=TRUE)
```

In the original file "file_name.txt" the lines are like this:

```
"2013-05-30",15,30,55,95

"2013-05-31",27,97,77,88

"2013-06-01",50,99,81,82
```

And I am reading every other line such that r outputs every other line to a text file. 
But the problem is that when I output to the text file titled "output_file_name.txt"
what the text file looks like is:

```
"2013-05-30",15,30,55,95 "2013-06-01",50,99,81,82
```

But what I need the text file to look like is :

```
"2013-05-30",15,30,55,95

"2013-06-01",50,99,81,82
```

The original text file is so large that it would be impossible to edit by hand.

Please help,

Thank you

Comment: Why have you set `sep=" "`? If you want them each on a new line I would think `sep="\n"` would be the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the `write` functions for writing to file. I think this does what you want.

```
> txt <- '"2013-05-30",15,30,55,95
 "2013-05-31",27,97,77,88
 "2013-06-01",50,99,81,82'
> test <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
> test <- test[seq(1, length(test), 2)]
> writeLines(test, sep = "\n") ## with  file = "filename" to write to file
"2013-05-30",15,30,55,95
"2013-06-01",50,99,81,82
```

All you needed was a `sep = "\n"` in there.  Or you could insert `"\n"` into the end of each string, but that's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Just use paste0 to append a "\n" to separate the lines:

```
cat( paste0(test, "\n"), file="E:/output_file_name.txt", sep = " ",append=TRUE)
```